# Split a string into several lists

Tags: python-3.x

So I am trying to convert a reverse polish mathematical expression that is presented as a list into a formula. I am trying to do this by splitting the expression into smaller sums and then combining them

This is the code I have so far

```
import re
expression = [15, 7, 1, 1, '+', '-', '/', 3, '*', 2, 1, 1, '+', '+', '-']
polish_expression = " ".join([str(i) for i in expression])

numbers  = re.split ("(\D\s)",polish_expression)

print(numbers)
```

but the output is:
`['15 7 1 1 ', '+ ', '', '- ', '', '/ ', '3 ', '* ', '2 1 1 ', '+ ', '', '+ ', '-']`

Can I get the desired output using regex (something along the lines of):
`[[15,7,1,1],["+","-","/"],[3],["*"],[2,1,1],["+","+","-"]]`

**Edit:**

```
import re
expression = [15, 7, 1, 1, '+', '-', '/', 3, '*', 2, 1, 1, '+', '+', '-']
polish_expression = "".join([str(i) for i in expression])
numbers  = filter(None, re.split ("(\d+)",polish_expression))
print(list(numbers))
```

Gets close but the numbers all appear a single string
`['15711', '+-/', '3', '*', '211', '++-']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex, the following code can produce the desired results

```
polish_expression = ' '.join(map(str, expression))
split_output = re.split(r'((?:\d+ )+)', polish_expression)
# ['', '15 7 1 1 ', '+ - / ', '3 ', '* ', '2 1 1 ', '+ + -']
stripped_output = [s.strip() for s in split_output if s]
# ['15 7 1 1', '+ - /', '3', '*', '2 1 1', '+ + -']
string_list_output = [s.split(' ') for s in stripped_output]
# [['15', '7', '1', '1'], ['+', '-', '/'], ['3'], ['*'], ['2', '1', '1'], ['+', '+', '-']]
desired_output = [list(map(int, item)) if item[0].isdigit() else item for item in string_op]
# [[15, 7, 1, 1], ['+', '-', '/'], [3], ['*'], [2, 1, 1], ['+', '+', '-']]
```

---

A simple non-regex solution would be:

If your `expression` list is a mix of `str` and `int` types as given in the question, the following code can be used:

```
output = [[expression[0]]]

for item in expression[1:]:
    if type(item) == type(output[op_index][0]):
        output[op_index].append(item)
    else:
        output.append([item])
        op_index += 1

print(output)
# [[15, 7, 1, 1], ['+', '-', '/'], [3], ['*'], [2, 1, 1], ['+', '+', '-']]
```

If they're all `str`, then you should be able to use `str.isdigit()` to differentiate.

Comment: Thanks. I want to try use regex as I just so happen to be learning about this at the moment hence why I am trying to achieve this result. Is it possible to get that output using regex?

Comment: I've added a regex based solution.